# Customizer API - Class doesn't exist error

Tags: theme-customizer

Currently I'm developing WordPress Theme.Within my theme I'm using Customizer API.I added some controls,setting,sections It works.

Also, I created new PHP file called `class-customizer-control.php`.Inside this file I'll put all custom controls, so I created one custom control (textarea):

```
<?php
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php';
/**
*    Add Custom controls to Customizer API
*/
function bedakb_gamer_customcontrols() {
    class Custom_Textarea_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
        public $type = 'textarea';

        public function render_content() {
            ?>
            <label>
                <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
                <textarea rows="5" style="width:100%;" <?php $this->link(); ?>><?php echo esc_textarea( $this->value() ); ?></textarea>
            </label>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
add_action('customize_register', 'bedakb_gamer_customcontrols');
?>
```

Next, I added control, inside customization file, that using Textarea custom control:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new Custom_Textarea_Control($wp_customize, 'bedakb_ad728', array(
    'label'        => __('Adsense 728x90', 'bedakb_gamer'),
    'section'    => 'bedakb_adsense',
    'priority'    => 10,
)));
```

But when I try to open Customization in Wp-admin, I got error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Custom_Textarea_Control' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wp2\wp-content\themes\bedakb_gamer\inc\customizer.php
>   on line 35

Comment: Why are you including files from `wp-includes`? You should include `class-customizer-control.php` from your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: class-customizer-control.php is already included in functions.php file.Same problem happened when I remove line that include wp-customize-control.php.

Comment: Why are you defining a class inside a function? It makes little sense

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there are different approaches for this, but this is a pattern I've implemented successfully in several places.

In my approach, I am including the "add_control" inside the function that contains the custom class. The $wp_customize object gets passed in to the main function.

Also, I'm not sure why you are trying to include class-wp-customize-control.php.

Here's my guess for what you need, assuming you've created the "bedakb_adsense" section elsewhere. Just put the following in a php file and call it from your functions.php

```
<?php

function bedakb_gamer_customcontrols($wp_customize) {

    class Custom_Textarea_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
        public $type = 'textarea';

        public function render_content() {
            ?>
            <label>
                <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
                <textarea rows="5" style="width:100%;" <?php $this->link(); ?>><?php echo esc_textarea( $this->value() ); ?></textarea>
            </label>
            <?php
        }
    }

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'bedakb_ad728', array(
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options'
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new Custom_Textarea_Control($wp_customize, 'bedakb_ad728', array(
        'label'        => __('Adsense 728x90', 'bedakb_gamer'),
        'section'    => 'bedakb_adsense',
        'priority'    => 10,
    )));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'bedakb_gamer_customcontrols', 99);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems.

First: I didn't add setting for custom control

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'bedakb_ad728', array(
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options'
));
```

Second: Into functions.php file `customizer.php` was included before `class-customizer-control.php`

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/class-customizer-control.php';
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';
```